# Expo gradle build failed

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo, eas

I do an Android Play Store build. Unfortunately it does not work.

This is the output

```
> Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/build.gradle' line: 40
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-application'.
> Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for task ':expo-application:androidSourcesJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================
2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/ExpoModulesCorePlugin.gradle' line: 65
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
> Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================
BUILD FAILED in 1m 50s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I created a bug here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/27001 it contains additinal informations

Answer (score 4):

`Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for task ':expo-application:androidSourcesJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.`

Check first if this is related to [`expo/expo` issue 26560](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/26560)

> I encountered an issue when running the '`androidSourcesJar`' task in my Android project using Gradle 8. I was trying to set the '`classifier`' property in a 'Jar' task, but it appears this property is no longer supported.
> Instead, I tried using '`archiveClassifier`' and it worked.

Instead of:

```java
task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
  classifier = 'sources'
  from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}
```

Use:

```java
task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
  archiveClassifier = 'sources'
  from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}
```

> This change is part of the [AbstractArchiveTask API Cleanup in Gradle 8](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#abstractarchivetask_api_cleanup).

This is also illustrated in [issue 23023](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/23023).

---

> I cannot modify the expo source code since expo is proprietary.
> I do not work for the company; hence I am not allowed to fix that code.

But you could fork the necessary Expo repository, apply the fix, and use your forked version as a dependency. That would allow you to control updates and apply fixes as needed without waiting for the upstream repository to incorporate your changes.

Or: use a post-install script in your project to apply patches automatically after npm/yarn installations. Tools like [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) can help you maintain your changes across package updates without directly modifying node_modules.

As a temporary workaround, consider using an earlier version of Gradle that does not have this issue

---

> The expo.dev-website do not let me change the grade version. See, I use the command `eas build` in the project-root, I have no idea where to add post-install-script.
> If I fork Expo, how will `eas build` address my fork as a dependency?

True, [`eas build`](https://docs.expo.dev/build/introduction/) being a hosted service for building app binaries for your Expo and React Native projects, it would not work with an Expo fork.

And [`app.json`](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/project-structure/#appjson) (which contains [configuration options](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app) for the project) does not provide a direct way to modify the Gradle version or apply a patch to the Expo modules.

That means the current version of Expo would not support yuor use case, not until that issue is resolved on Expo's side.

Comment: Hm, I can not modify the expo sourcecode since expo is proprietary. I do not work for the company, hence I am not allowed to fix that code.

Comment: The expo.dev-website do not let me change the grade version. See, I use the command `eas build` in the project-root, I have no idea where to add post-install-script. If I fork expo, how will `eas build` address my fork as a dependency?

Comment: However, I have a `app.json`, having a `expo`/`android` scope, should I add something here?

Comment: @Grim I have edited the answer to address your questions.

Comment: Ah, so there is nothing I can do right now.

Comment: @Grim Beside making sure the bug is reported to the Expo project, so far, I haven't seen any other option.